# Jewish View on "Runes"

Tags: talmud-bavli

How does the Torah and Talmud view (viking and non viking) runes? Letters written on swords and such. Stones with a letters. What is the view on them?

To clarify: There is a game(s) where it is possible to enhance weapons and armor by adding runes to them like a rune of fire that would make it stronger. Would this be nonkosher?

Comment: What problem do you think there might be?

Comment: Why would there be any view on them?

Comment: @N.T. Considering the fairly well-developed Norse mythology that likely accompanied the runes, this likely becomes a question of engaging with an avodah zarah.

Comment: @Yehuda Could be that, or I recall some telling me "I heard some of the Vikings might have come from the lost ten tribes!" but it never seemed reliable to me. I do recall the idea that the Vikings may have come to North America before Columbus and maybe brought language similar to Hebrew, so maybe the idea is based on that, but I'm not sure.

Midrash has lots of interesting insight about other cultures regardless

Comment: @ShipBuilding What you are recalling is the association between Denmark and the tribe of Dan. Regarding Runes, there is a long standing tradition in the Torah for the writing of Angel script on tools and weapons. Consider the kabbalistic text, the Sword of Moshe, and also the two edged, flaming sword mentioned in Bereshit 3:24. It would seem likely that the tradition of Runes evolved from one of the variants of Angel script. Each Angel has a distinct and unique Alphabet and seal. This tradition is discussed in both Temani manuscripts and those from the Gaonim.

Comment: @ShipBuilding There is also a tradition by some people in Finland that they are descendants of the tribe of Yissachar.

Comment: @Yehuda That is like saying "What is the Jewish position on English, because of the King James Bible?"

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thanks for posting that Yaacov, that's fascinating about the runes especially. I had heard about the Sword of Moshe but I never conceptualized the flaming sword literally enough to think it also had runes on it. But it wouldn't have to be literal, it could just be the alphabet "engraved" in the spiritual sense that Sefer Yetzirah discusses "engraved letters." 

I wonder how this fits with the debate about what is the oldest language? I believe Hebrew, as per Torah tradition, but people keep presenting me with difficult archaeological counterpoints I dont know how to answer

Comment: @ShipBuilding You’re welcome. On the archeological side, there are fairly recent discoveries at what is believed to be the alter site of Shalem used by Malchitzedek. It has engravings in the stones which to me are clearly Angel script. And this is the same tradition which is taught in connection with what was passed down from Adam HaRishon to his descendants via Metushelach (linguistically ‘the Angel of Death’), Chanoch, Noach, Shem and Ever to Avram/Avraham. Remember Tehillim 85:12, Truth will sprout from the earth…”.

Comment: @N.T. 1. That depends on the usage of the runes. Are they exclusively used in religious literature, or are they used for Viking comic books as well? 2. I do believe the Satmar Rov discussed issues like this in his Maamar Lashon Hakodesh in the Vayoel Moshe, but I haven't learned it through yet to say that conclusively.

Comment: @Yehuda 1. is off topic for this site.

Answer (score 6):

> How does the Torah and Talmud view (viking and non viking) runes?

The Torah and Hazal make no explicit reference to the runic alphabets. It would be exceedingly difficult to argue that they had any direct knowledge of them. The earliest possible reference one might reasonably expect to find would be in the later medieval literature of Ashkenaz.

> Letters written on swords and such. Stones with a letters. What is the view on them?

There is no prohibition against writing on stones or weapons. If there were some talismanic/occultic significance intended then there may be an issue. In such instances the issue would stem from the intent and purpose of the writing not from the writing in and of itself. The precise use case in each instance would need to be ascertained before any kind of halakhic analysis could be made.

Comment: Isn't Talmud Bavli for talismanics? It explicitly states an amulet that had successfully healed is kosher in some sense. Also what sort of writing could be without purpose? Even writing the owner's name would have the purpose of making it his property?

Comment: @IsraelB. the topic of talismans, amulets, etc. each need to be discussed independently and with case specifics in mind. Addressing such large topics על רגל אחת in the comments is unlikely to be productive. The main point I raise is that the use of inscriptions *could* invoke various concerns under the broad umbrella of עבודה זרה and its related fields.  To determine whether a particular action/object is prohibited, the details specific to the case would need to be raised for the purpose of analysis.